# Stop infinity Thread in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a function that is running as an infinity process as a thread, and doing some operations during it. Then I need to be able to stop that thread. How can I do that?

Adding schema of the function and logic that I have:

```
def infinity_thread_function():
    status, res = OSHelperClass.execute("infinity command") # execute OS call that does not stop

def thread_starter():
    thread_player = threading.Thread(target=infinity_thread_function, daemon=True)
    # Here is some logic
    # ......
    # !!!HERE I NEED TO STOP THE THREAD

thread_starter()
```

Comment: Whatever you are running should provide a way to stop itself gracefuly. Otherwise your only option is to kill it. Which is not good.